# Issues with copying over an OS to the boot drive

Tags: linux, boot

So we have installation medias, for booting to rudimentary setups, or live medias, for booting to the OSes themselves, for installation of said OS.

I was wondering how problematic to simply copy over from an ISO from which you create these medias, using unpacking tools, the entire boot disk image. Specifically a Linux distro. Say, hypothetically, I can just physically take out the drive, connect it to another computer & then "unpack" the ISO.

The main issue is the configuration. It would have to be set up to the new host system, which is detected by the installation environment. Perhaps there could be a pre-set list of configurations for most devices/builds (PC, laptop/netbook/tablet/phone series)?

Is there a project providing such tool?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the ISO to the disk will not result in a bootable installation.

The ISO is an
[Optical disc image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_image):

> An optical disc image (or ISO image, from the ISO 9660 file system used with CD-ROM media) is a disk image that contains everything that would be written to an optical disc, disk sector by disc sector, including the optical disc file system.

The BIOS/UEFI knows the difference between a removable device,
such as CD/DVD/USB, and an internal hard disk, so will use different
boot algorithms.

The ISO does not have the right disk format (NTFS, ext4 etc.) that the
BIOS/UEFI wil expect, nor will it have the right boot sector,
EFI partition etc.

Therefore there are no projects for doing such a direct copy.
An installer must create the correct disk partitions and establish the
boot environment.
Following that, the rest is indeed almost just a straight copy
(with some small additions), before the operating system can
boot from the hard disk and complete its own installation.

Comment: No, I’m not referring to copying the filesystem as-is from the ISO. More like if the ISO, burnt into a media, had been booted into and hypothetically installed to the hard drive while it is the host system. Now, if said partition that was just set-up was isolated (say with some booting hardware emulation akin to Hyper-V), can it had been simply copied over to the hard drive instead?

Comment: Are you referring to disk cloning (one partition is usually not enough)? Or are you asking about using `dd` from an disk where the OS is already installed to a new disk?

Comment: Binary cloning or **dd** file transfer might’ve worked, if the systems I’m mainly working on are very similar. Instead, I have an x86 machine to edit the images & an ARM-HF tablet I’m trying to install a Linux distro to. So, very different configurations. Let’s just say with the tablet, I can’t get around SecureBoot to boot the medias & I’m locked out of the UEFI. However, the Win 8.1 RT Recovery image boots just fine. So, copying the Linux installation from Windows Recovery is a viable option, as I see it.

Comment: Are you able to connect USB to the tablet, and can you boot from it?